# unicode path oledb issue

Tags: windows, oledb, jet

I am maintaining some old code and I ran into an unexpected error on connecting to an MSAccess database in windows 7 through Jet.OleDB

In windows 7 the following code fails because the path is is not found by the driver.  The same code in windows xp and windows 10 works and throws the expected error (because the .mdb file is empty)

```
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace unicode_oledb_problem
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = @"ł.mdb";
            using (System.IO.File.Create(path)) { }
            string connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};", path);
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                // windows xp: OleDbException - Unrecognized database format
                // windows 7: OleDbException - Could not find file: ...
                // windows 10: OleDbException - Unrecognized database format
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well as you just create an empty file it isn't a database of any kind. "ł.mdb" is not a path to anywhere and your program would expect to find the database on the PATH, probably in the same place as the .exe. The errors are essentially saying there's an issue with the db. The actual text of errors can be misleading. Do your code a favor and tell it where the database actually is and not leave it to random events external to your program to resolve it's location. Also, what on earth is "ł". May I also suggest you call your database something other than that when you do create it properly.

Comment: My intention was to make a minimally verifiable example to show that for some reason certain characters are not handled well in windows 7 using Jet/mdb.  The sucessful execution of the File.Create line ensures the database path exists.  I think it's reasonable to assume that attempting to open an empty file should result in something like "unrecognized database format", and not "could not find file". Additionally I went to the trouble of running it on 3 different operating systems since I am really hoping for an easy workaround to resolve bugs caused by this.